# After running pulling out the ip address and exporting to a text file, I need to place one more piece of info in to the sheet

Tags: powershell

I am at a lost here.  I have 20,000 lines in a tab delimited text file.  One of the lines are below.  I need to extract the ip's and the username, which is located near the end of the line. I have figured out how to strip the ip's and put them in the text file, but how can I get the username in the same text file and keep that user name associated with the ip's in the line?  I have placed my code at the bottom.  I think I have the proper regular expression to pull the $Name but I am not sure...The name are all lastname, firstname

Mike Joung  8/21/2012 2:36  gdnwgx9495j;10.2.135.56;359;2013/11/13 08:21:13gdnm8xyydv1;10.2.135.20;1;2013/08/09 09:20:51gdnm592;10.2.132.205;1;2012/08/30 13:26:42gdnw0225;10.2.132.229;1;2012/08/30 13:17:28gdnmh0lydv1;10.7.101.54;14;2012/07/27 01:15:37      6/12/2012 8:00  11/23/2009 5:26 Joung, Mike Never

```
    $input_path = ‘c:\ps\EMEA_wNotes_only.txt’
    $output_file = ‘c:\ps\extracted_ip_addresses.txt’
    $regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’
    $Name = ‘\b[A-Za-z0-20._%-]+\b’
    select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Comment: If the file is truly tab delimited, use `Import-Csv $input_path`.  That will get you back an array of objects (one for every line) with properties corresponding to the TSV fields.  However I didn't see any tabs in the text you pasted.  In fact, it looks like ';' is also being used as a delimeter.

Comment: This sheet is a mess!  What I meant to say is that there are "+" delimited fields in this sheet Ramzi elhassan+11/8/2013 9:35:23 AM+riym75lk4r1;10.143.114.103;305;2013/11/13 19:19:49<Cr/Lf>riym30069538;10.143.114.88;1;2013/04/28 11:28:15<Cr/Lf>riym1031;192.168.1.121;427;2012/08/26 12:00:50<Cr/Lf>riym1010;10.143.114.120;1;2012/03/17 10:00:02<Cr/Lf>caimkoshy;10.3.96.59;1;2011/12/23 13:51:49<Cr/Lf>+10/17/2013 8:47:34 PM+10/8/2013 1:52:34 AM+10/23/2003 9:51:05 AM+El Hassan, Ramzi M. (GGO)+++Never

Comment: If you open that as a csv file and use the + sign as the delimter, you will see the nightmare in the NOTES field I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KeithHill is right on the money about `Import-Csv`, but after looking at your example line, I don't think it will be that simple. Is every line the same format? That is, does every line have the same number of fields?  It looks like, from your example, that you have a few fields that each consist of semi-colon separated data, with the username being the second to last tab separated field.

If I haven't completely confused myself here, you can take advantage of some of PowerShells nifty array indexing features.

```
$input_path = ‘c:\ps\EMEA_wNotes_only.txt’
$output_file = ‘c:\ps\extracted_ip_addresses.txt’
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’
Get-Content $input_path | % { $_ -split "`t" } | Select-Object @{Name="uname";Expression={$_[-2]}},@{Name="ips";Expression={($_ | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches) -Join ","}} | Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```

Basically, we are treating each line individually, and manual splitting it on the tabs into an array, which we then pull the second to last item out of. (Or whatever number it is from the end of the array. Then we transform that array by looking at each item in it using select string to pull out the ips, join the ips with commas, wash, rinse andd repeat, then export it all to a cvs file.

The cvs file should be something like

```
User name,ip,ip,ip
```

But the ips might be surrounded by quotes, like

```
User name,"ip,ip,ip"
```

I don't remember, and I can't test it on the iPad here ;)
Hopefully this helps some.